# How do you prevent reload loop when checking login?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have been struggling with this all day and have not found an answer.  I am using CodeIgniter.

The problem is that when the person gets to the home page, I want to check whether or not they are logged in.  If they are not, I want them to be able to view the home page.  If they are, they should go straight to their dashboard.

I understand that the issue is that the index function is running repeatedly causing the redirects, but I have not been able to find a workaround.

This was working perfectly until I removed index.php and made my homepage my login page.

Here is my code:

```
 function index(){  
    if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in())
    {
        redirect('home', 'refresh');
    }
    elseif (!$this->ion_auth->is_admin())
    {
        //redirect them to the home page because they must be an administrator to view this
        redirect('user/dashboard', 'refresh');
    }
    else
    {
        //set the flash data error message if there is one
        $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors()) ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message');

        //list the users
        $this->data['users'] = $this->ion_auth->users()->result();
        foreach ($this->data['users'] as $k => $user)
        {
            $this->data['users'][$k]->groups = $this->ion_auth->get_users_groups($user->id)->result();
        }

        //$this->_render_page('auth/index', $this->data);
        redirect('user/dashboard', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

My default controller is the auth (which tracks the logins).  Let me know if I need to provide any other pieces of code.

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking for Help searching an existent Answer or external Resource.

Comment: I have been searching for help and answers all day and haven't been able to find a solution.  I am truly stuck.

Comment: Yes, but this does not qualify a reason to place a call for help here. This website is about programing questions. And as you ask if you can provide better: Yes you can: See this check-list? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist - add this to your question and write below each point of the checklist what you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in())
{
     redirect('home', 'refresh'); // remove this line
     //load your view files instead
     // the redirect is loading this  index function repeatedly 
}
```